# Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer when running AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp in android studio kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

i trying to make application with google calendar api and following google documentation.
but I found this error and showed it to AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp function

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer;

can someone tell me how this can happen and how to solve it?
this is my code

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT: NetHttpTransport): Credential? {
        // Load client secrets.
        val `in`: InputStream = assets.open(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
        val clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, InputStreamReader(`in`))

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        val tokenFolder = File(
            "${getExternalFilesDir(null)}${File.separator.toString() + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH}"
        )
        if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
            tokenFolder.mkdirs()
        }
        val acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        val username = acct?.id

        val flow = (GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES
        )
            .setDataStoreFactory(FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder))
            .setAccessType("offline")).build()
        val receiver = (LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888)).build()
        //returns an authorized Credential object.

        return AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize(username)
    }
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for your problem? I'm stuck with the same problem right now.

Comment: Did anyone get a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found by looking at other similar issues is that its a dependency version issue, I switched to an older version of dependencies and got a bit further than this.

the the dependencies i used:

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.32.1'
implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.30.4'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev20220927-2.0.0'
```